# Scrapy: Multi form requests fail without error

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I wrote a spider that starts with multi form requests alternated by a changing parameter, in this way:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = “Test Spider“

    allowed_domains = [“somewhere.com”]

    PARAMS = [
        ‘FOO’,
        ‘BAR’,
        etc
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for param in self.PARAMS:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                "http://somewhere.com/search.do?action=advanced",
                formdata={
                    ‘param’: param
                },
                callback=self.__first_page,
                meta={'cookiejar': 'initial-session’,’param’: param}
            )

    def __first_page(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            "http://somewhere.com/advancedSearch.do?action=firstPage",
            formdata={
                ‘param’: param
            },
            callback=self._first_page_search,
            meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']}
        )

    def _first_page_search(self, response):
        yield self.__applications_page(response, '1')

    def __applications_page(self, response, page):
        return scrapy.FormRequest(
            "http://somewhere.com/pagedSearch.do",
            formdata={
                'searchCriteria.page': page
            },
            callback=self.__parse_data,
            meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar'], 'page': page}
        )

    def __parse_data(self, response):
        page = response.meta['page']
        if page == '1':
            number_of_pages = len(response.xpath('//div[@id="searchResultsContainer"]/p[@class="pager top"]/a[@class="page"]/@href').extract())
            print "NUMBER OF PAGES",number_of_pages
            for p in range(2, number_of_pages + 2):
                yield self.__applications_page(response, str(p))

        links = response.xpath('//ul[@id="searchresults"]//li[@class="searchresult"]/a/@href').extract()
        for url in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url='http://somewhere.com' + url, callback=self.__parse_single_item)

    def __parse_single_item(self, response):
        item = MyData.MyData()
        …

    return item
```

The crawling is ok when there is only one item in `PARAMS` at the beginning. So if it run only against `FOO` or `BAR`, etc, I get the correct scraped data. When I have all the params (21 is the complete list), the process fails as it looks like only 2/3 params are attempted to be scraped and the process exits without any error (no `500`s, only `200`s and no generic Python errors).

Is there any error in the way I wrote the spider?